# Apache Shiro plugin integration with multitenancy plugin in grails

Tags: java, maven, grails, shiro, multi-tenant

I have a special case that I have to use **compile  'multi-tenant-single-db-0.8.3'** and **compile ":shiro:1.2.1"** together for the case below:-

Having Group domain as Tenant so that, A User(Shiro user used for Authentication) must be unique in it's group / tenant. i.e. User may be duplicate outside it's tenant.So, a user say test@gmail.com  in Group A may also be there in another Group B and so may be in C and so on.

Below are the User and group domains that I have:-

```
@MultiTenant
class User {
     String username
     String password
     Group group
 }
```

---

```
class Group implements Tenant {
    String name

    static belongsTo = [parent: Group]
    static hasMany = [users: User]
}
```

---

```
class RestRealm {

    def restService

    static authTokenClass = ru.grails.security.RestToken

    def authenticate(authToken) {
        log.info "Attempting to authenticate ${authToken.token} in REST realm..."
        def token = authToken.token

        // If we don't have user for specified token then user is not authenticated
        def username = restService.getUsernameForToken(token)
        **def user = User.findByEmail(username)**


        if (!user) {
            throw new UnknownAccountException("No account found for token [${token}]")
        }
        if (user?.status == PartyStatus.INACTIVE) {
            throw new InactiveUserException();
        }
        log.info "Found user '${user.email}' in DB"
        return new SimpleAccount(user.email, user.password, "RestRealm")
    }

}
```

Multitenancy plugin don't work inside the realms (see code among **s.This user must be fetch only from current tenant that has already been set using DomainTenantResolver which implements TenantResolver) and the restservice that I have created to handle Shiro login. One obvious solution that I found is to override functionality of Shiro plugin to handle multitenancy.

Did a lot of search for if there has been some other plugin or Jar over maven to solve this case, but in vain.
But I am puzzled whether there is some solution to this problem that has been implemented by anyone else or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried using the Shiro plugin with [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com)? Stormpath has Shiro integration and supports multi-tenancy in its data model natively.

Comment: Already using shiro and multitenant-single-db plugin and can't afford to go for Stormpath.Do we have other alternative?